# Pass 'this' value to another funcion in Dart and call some method

Tags: function, delegates, dart, parameter-passing

it's possible this scenario. Class 1:

```
    class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
      AppComponent() {
        Class2 pippo = new Class2()
        pippo.passAppComponent(this);
      }

      void printHelloInAppComponent(){
        print('hello');
      }
    }
```

Class 2:

```
  class Class2  {
    func passAppComponent(dynamic scope) {
      scope.printHelloInAppComponent();
    }
  }
```

If i try this i take this error:

> EXCEPTION: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '$indexSet' (C.JSNull_methods.$indexSet is not a function) in [null]

Comment: The error message says that you are doing an "index set" (that is `something[index] = value` on `null`. I don't see any `[]=` operation in your code at all, so maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works almost

```
void main() {
  new AppComponent();
}

class AppComponent /*implements OnInit*/  {
  AppComponent() {
    Class2 pippo = new Class2();
    pippo.passAppComponent(this);
  }

  void printHelloInAppComponent(){
    print('hello');
  }
}

class Class2  {
  /* func */ passAppComponent(dynamic scope) {
    scope.printHelloInAppComponent();
  }
}
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b79daa4e2679d45d56b1)